# How to get all users that can acces or view a file?

Tags: box-api

I need to get all users that have view permissions over a file. 
I´m watching this http://developers.box.com/docs/, but only can see the creator, the owner and the last user who modified the file.
Is there any way to get this?
Thanks, Cristian

Answer (score 1):

Permissions in Box are handled on the folder level. In order to figure out what users have access to a given file, you would need to [get the 'collaborations' on its parent folder](http://developers.box.com/docs/#folders-view-a-folders-collaborations) e.g. for file 123 contained in folder ABC I would do

```
GET https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/ABC/collaborations
```